# Override interface function?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

The interface `ExecutorInterface` has a function called `doStuff()`. My class `Executor` implements interface `ExecutorInterface` and overrides `doStuff()`.

Interface function `doStuff()`calls the method `getData()`. If I override the function `doStuff()`, will `getData()` still be called? How could I add functionality to `doStuff()` without losing the original functionality?

Comment: "interface function": (1) Java doesn't have "functions", it has methods (the distinction is that methods are called _on an object_ while functions aren't). (2) Do you mean that the interface has a _default_ method?

Comment: *"Interface function doStuff()calls the method getData()"* Is it a `default` method? @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- what about `java.util.funciton.Function` and lambdas? `;)`

Comment: @BenjaminM Those aren't functions, they're instances of a type named `Function`.

Comment: IMHO it's meaningless discussion about definitions - `static methods` in Java, especially when it comes to some utilities, is so incorrect due to method/function definition

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familiar with technical terms. I started with PHP and am currently learning Java -- which is the reason why I referred to methods as functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot unless you will call explicitly the original method (what is usually a case to be honest)

```
class Executor implements ExecutorInterface {
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        ExecutorInterface.super.doStuff();
        // some additional logic
    }
}
```

Read more here (due to edit - it's not really helpful, Oracle is not describing here calling default class as super):

- [using the keyword super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Read this rather:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I understand you correctly, `super.doStuff();` will include the functionality of the original method?

Comment: No, `super` is for parent class, so this error occurs because this method doesn't exist in `Object`, only in the interface.

Comment: @MoisésCunha So, I can't use `super` to include the functionality of the method from the interface?

Comment: I'm sorry I mislead you a little bit - indeed in case of interface default method this super call looks slightly different - I edited answer

Comment: The reason of such difference is that in Java you may implement multiple interfaces and all of them could have the same method (and different default implementations) therefore you need to call this even more explicitly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the `getData` method on the method override. For this to work, the `getData` method must be a `public` method within the interface

```
interface ExecutorInterface  {
    void doStuff();

    default void getData() {
        System.out.println("getData");
    }
}


class Executor implements ExecutorInterface{
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        getData();
        //rest of the code
    }
}
```

A better way would be for you to make an `abstract class`

```
abstract class ExecutorAbstract  {
    public void doStuff(){
        getData();
    }

    private void getData() {
        System.out.println("getData");
    }
}

class Executor extends ExecutorAbstract{
    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        super.doStuff();
        //rest of the code
    }
}
```

This way the `getData` method would not be changed by any other class, besides being necessary to call `super.doStuff()` to invoke `getData`

Comment: Thanks! Seems like I might want to use an abstract class instead.

Comment: Like the interface, you cannot create an instance of an `abstract class`. It is only meant to be extended as a superclass.